# Meaning of the word "easy" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

It's from the third episode of the second season of *the Walking Dead*. Here is the context:

> Rick: (in the background) The principal's car right out of the
> teacher's lot in the middle of a school day. Shane steps out of lunch
> and makes a beeline to Kingsley's Hyundai...(chuckles) Wires the
> ignition,peels out,drives down Dylan drive to that chicken farm out
> there. You've heard this before,right? So he pulls it into one of the
> big holding pens. Kingsley,he waxed that thing every month;had the
> auto shop vacuum it out every week. Shane,he parks it in this huge pen
> with a couple of hundred Rhode Island reds. He busts open bags of seed
> in the back seat,rolls down all the windows,and then starts sprinting
> back to school. It's three miles away **easy**. He's back in time to
> finish his sandwich before the bell. And then the bell rings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not grammatically correct English, but someone attempting a colloquial accent in dialog (well, monologue, really). The sentence *should* be, "It's three miles away, easily." Here, *easily* is used in the sense of *at least*, or *beyond, with room for error*. Another example:

```
The ball flew over the bleachers, easily a home run.
```

Answer (score 1):

'Three miles away easy' is a casual or dialect way of saying 'without doubt, at least three miles away'. More formally, you can say 'it is easily three miles away'.

[Easily (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/easily)